# TicTacToe Problems

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, do-while

I am stuck on my tictactoe problem. Define a calss called TicTacToe. An object of type TicTacToe is a single game of TicTacToe. Store the game board as a single 2d array of base type char that has three rows and three columns. Include methods to add a move, display the board, to tell whose turn it is, to tell whether there is a winnner, to say who the winner is, and to restart the game to the beginning. Write a main method for the class that will allow two players to enter their moves in turn at the same keyboard.

I have some of my methods written and have been testing as I go. When I test my code I either get it to place a mark but also print out invalid entry or it will continuously loop through asking for a move and then saying the space is occupied. I can't figure out how to fix that. I'm sure it has something to do with my do while loop and the boolean methods for isEmpty and notValid. Also I'm stuck on how to implement a counter for each player's win.

Here is my code:

```
    public void addMove()
    {
        checkTurn();
        int row, col;
        do
        {
        System.out.println("Enter a row (1-3): ");
        row = in.nextInt() - 1; //Array index starts at 0.
        System.out.println("Enter a column (1-3): ");
        col = in.nextInt() - 1;

        if (row>=0 && row<ROWS)
            if(col>=0 && col<COLUMNS)
                if (playerX)
                    {
                        gameBoard[row][col] = player1Move;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        gameBoard[row][col] = player2Move;
                    }
         checkForWin();
         changePlayer();
        }while (notValid(row,col));

            System.out.println("Invaild Entry.");
            //System.exit(0); 

        //checkForWin();
        //changePlayer();
    }
    public boolean notValid(int row, int col)
    {
        if (row < 0 || row > ROWS )
            return true;
        if (col < 0 || col > COLUMNS)
            return true;
        if (!isEmpty(row,col))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(int row, int col)
    {
        if(gameBoard[row][col]==' ')
            return true;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Space is already occupied.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my testing class:

```
public class TicTacToe
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    TicTacToeClass game = new TicTacToeClass();
    game.addMove();
    game.printBoard();


    }

}
```

Comment: This is what debuggers were made for, not us.

Comment: I do not know how to use the debugger in eclipse.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It the button next to Run.  Unless this is the last program you will ever have a bug in, learning how to use a debugger is an essential skill.

Comment: @Sarah You set a break-point somewhere, if you want it can be the very first line of your main method, and then start the program with the debug button, rather than the run button. Personally, I would also recommend Intellij IDEA for coding in Java, it's a much more enjoyable Java experience in every way.

Comment: @Sarah: This is the perfect opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger then.  You have all the tools available to get the information you need about this or any other problem you encounter.  The code isn't a black box, you *can* examine it with a debugger.

Comment: You're setting the space to have an 'X' or 'O' in it, and _then_ checking if it's empty... It'll never be empty if you just set the value. You need to make sure the space is empty _before_ setting the values.

Comment: Damnit @PeterLawrey you just made me spit water all over my keyboard. =)

Comment: @Sarah Then google "[how to debug in eclipse](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+debug+in+eclipse)"

Comment: @pushasha thanks for actually trying to help me answer my question. Excuse me for being new to coding and not getting any review in my online class on how to use a debugger. also I am required to use eclipse for my class.

Comment: @Sarah Heh, no problem. Did you understand my explanation? That the 'notValid' method needs to be called before you set the values in AddMove()?

Comment: Eclipse is just fine. Preference for tools is a personal thing. Ignore tool bigots.

Comment: @pushasha yeah, i understand. I'm just trying to figure out how to rewrite the code.

Comment: I'll also add that your "Invalid Entry" Println statement will be called after a valid entry is made, because it'll be executed after the do-while loop finishes (which only finishes after a valid entry is made). That should probably go in the "notValid" method instead.

Comment: To clarify ... The user enters a move, then in notValid you check to see that the space you already put the X in is empty, Since you put a value of X  it will never be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will let you handle the multiple game part. This plays one game and exits.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToe
{
    private final static int ROWS = 3;
    private final static int COLUMNS = 3;
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    private int player1WinCount = 0;
    private int player2WinCount = 0; 
    private char player1Move = 'X', player2Move = 'O';
    private boolean playerX = true;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public TicTacToe()
    {
        gameBoard  = new char [ROWS][COLUMNS];
        playerX = true;
        startGame();
    }

    //Initiate the game board with all empty spaces. 
    public void startGame()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) //Loop through rows.
            for(int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) //Loop through columns.
                gameBoard[row][col]= ' ';
    }

    public boolean checkTurn()
    {
        if (playerX)
        {
            System.out.println("Player X's turn.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Player O's turn.");
        }
        return playerX;
    }

    public void addMove()
    {
        int row, col;
        do
        {
        checkTurn();
        System.out.println("Enter a row (1-3): ");
        row = in.nextInt() - 1; //Array index starts at 0.
        System.out.println("Enter a column (1-3): ");
        col = in.nextInt() - 1;

        if(notValid(row,col)){
            // do not proceed
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry.");
            continue;
        }

        if (row>=0 && row<ROWS)
            if(col>=0 && col<COLUMNS)
                if (playerX)
                    {
                        gameBoard[row][col] = player1Move;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        gameBoard[row][col] = player2Move;
                    }
         boolean hasWon = checkForWin();
         if(hasWon)
         {
             System.out.println("You won");
             if(playerX)
             {
                 player1WinCount++;          
             }
             else
             {
                 player2WinCount++;
             }
             break;
         }
         changePlayer();
        }while (true);
    }

    public boolean notValid(int row, int col)
    {
        if (row < 0 || row > (ROWS - 1))
            return true;
        if (col < 0 || col > (COLUMNS - 1))
            return true;
        if (!isEmpty(row,col))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(int row, int col)
    {
        if(gameBoard[row][col]==' ')
            return true;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Space is already occupied.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void changePlayer()
    {
        if (playerX)
        {
            playerX = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerX = true;
        }
    }
    public void printBoard()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++)
            {        
                System.out.print("" + gameBoard[row][col]);
                if(col == 0 || col == 1)
                    System.out.print("|");

            }
            if (row ==0 || row ==1)
            System.out.print("\n-----\n");
        }   
    }
    /**
     * This method checks to see if a winner.
     * return true is there is a winner. 
     */
    public boolean checkForWin()
    {
        //checks rows for win
        for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row ++)
        {
            if (gameBoard[row][0] == gameBoard[row][1] && gameBoard[row][1]==gameBoard[row][2] && gameBoard[row][0]!= ' ')
            return true;    
        }       
        //checks columns for wins.
        for (int col = 0;  col < COLUMNS; col++)
        {   
            if (gameBoard[0][col] == gameBoard[1][col]&& gameBoard[1][col]==gameBoard[2][col] && gameBoard[0][col]!= ' ')
            return true;
        }
        //check the diagonals for wins.
        if (gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0]!= ' ')
            return true;
        if (gameBoard[2][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[0][2] && gameBoard[0][2]!= ' ')
            return true;

        return false; 
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
        game.addMove();
        game.printBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I was able to figure out how to fix the isvalid method but was still a little stumped on the winner count.

Comment: @Sarah look at the addMove method and check for hasWon and who just played.